# How can I do multiple substitutions using regex?

Tags: python, regex, string

I can use this code below to create a new file with the substitution of `a` with `aa` using regular expressions.

```
import re

with open("notes.txt") as text:
    new_text = re.sub("a", "aa", text.read())
    with open("notes2.txt", "w") as result:
        result.write(new_text)
```

I was wondering do I have to use this line, `new_text = re.sub("a", "aa", text.read())`, multiple times but substitute the string for others letters that I want to change in order to change more than one letter in my text?

That is, so `a`-->`aa`,`b`--> `bb` and `c`--> `cc`.

So I have to write that line for all the letters I want to change or is there an easier way. Perhaps to create a "dictionary" of translations. Should I put those letters into an array? I'm not sure how to call on them if I do.

Answer (score 92, accepted):

The [answer proposed by @nhahtdh](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15175193) is valid, but I would argue less pythonic than the canonical example, which uses code less opaque than his regex manipulations and takes advantage of python's built-in data structures and anonymous function feature.

A dictionary of translations makes sense in this context. In fact, that's how the Python Cookbook does it, as shown in this example (copied with modification from ActiveState: [Single-pass Multiple Replace](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/81330-single-pass-multiple-replace/))

```
import re 

def multiple_replace(replacements, text):
    # Create a regular expression from the dictionary keys
    regex = re.compile("(%s)" % "|".join(map(re.escape, replacements.keys())))
    # For each match, look-up corresponding value in dictionary
    return regex.sub(lambda mo: replacements[mo.group()], text) 

if __name__ == "__main__":
    s = "Larry Wall is the creator of Perl"
    d = {
        "Larry Wall": "Guido van Rossum",
        "creator": "Benevolent Dictator for Life",
        "Perl": "Python",
    }
    print multiple_replace(d, s)
```

So in your case, you could make a dict `trans = {"a": "aa", "b": "bb"}` and then pass it into `multiple_replace` along with the text you want translated. Basically all that function is doing is creating one huge regex containing all of your strings to translate, then when one is found, using the lambda function in `regex.sub` to perform the translation dictionary lookup.

You could use this function while reading from your file, for example:

```
with open("notes.txt") as text:
    new_text = multiple_replace(replacements, text.read())

with open("notes2.txt", "w") as result:
    result.write(new_text)
```

I've actually used this exact method in production, in a case where I needed to translate the months of the year from Czech into English for a web scraping task.

As @nhahtdh pointed out, one downside to this approach is that it is not prefix-free: dictionary keys that are prefixes of other dictionary keys will cause the method to break.

Comment: Wow thanks is pretty much what I was looking for. I have one more basic question, how do I ignore uppercase letters? So if I had A and I wanted to also translate that to aa without adding it to the dictionary.

Comment: @Euridice01: If you want to ignore case, specify `re.I` flag in `re.compile`.

Comment: Your current solution is not yet configure for the use case where there exists a pair of word, one of which is prefix of the other. The order of appearance in the alternation matter. I think at least you should state this assumption.

Comment: Your dict may not contain regex, so dict = {"\s":""} does not strip spaces (though dict = { " ":""} will )

Comment: Thanks for the codes! It works great! But we can't use Regex in the `dict` right? Like in the dict, writing "w.*?d":"you" ?

Comment: I can't get re:I to work in this case (as per the suggestion by @nhahtdh)
Penny: I can't see how it's possible to use wildcards in this case. I've tried by without success.

Comment: @thescoop: Ask a new question with your code. And if you want to use regex in the map, you would need to rewrite the function to remove the re.escape in the compile and change the custom replacement function to look for which group is responsible for the match and look up the corresponding replacement (in which case the input should be an array of tuples rather than dict).

Comment: Would someone please explain what this lambda does exactly in the return statement? Is there a simpler way to do it? I am not that familiar with the lambda expressions yet.

Comment: Awesome answer! I used this approach in a script ("hn.py", available on GitHub) where I use a dictionary to invoke multiple changes to lines in a file, and save those results (in situ). https://github.com/victoriastuart/hacker_news_scraper

Comment: if I use OrderedDict will the replacements happen in ORDER ??

Comment: This can be simplified by replacing `mo.string[mo.start():mo.end()]` with `mo.group()`, since they are equivalent, as mentioned in the docs [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.Match.end)

Comment: What if the I want the pattern replacement to be done with a function?

Comment: @oeter You can just put it in, in place of the lambda. A lambda is just an anonymous function. (I'm assuming you want to wrap the dict in some way, otherwise you'd need a bit of a different approach and that'd be off-topic for this thread.)

Comment: @ex1led As it says, the lambda is used "to perform the translation dictionary lookup". There's no simpler method for doing it, but the implementation could be simplified and I actually edited to do that just now, following Johnny's comment. I also clarified the explanation if that helps.

Comment: @wjandrea not to worry, after 3 years, it all makes sense

Comment: @nhahtdh: The use of \b boundary character at the beginning and end of each pattern will solve the prefix problem. Worked for me.

Answer (score 26):

You can use capturing group and backreference:

```
re.sub(r"([characters])", r"\1\1", text.read())
```

Put characters that you want to double up in between `[]`. For the case of lower case `a`, `b`, `c`:

```
re.sub(r"([abc])", r"\1\1", text.read())
```

In the replacement string, you can refer to whatever matched by a capturing group `()` with `\n` notation where `n` is some **positive** integer (0 excluded). `\1` refers to the first capturing group. There is another notation `\g<n>` where `n` can be any non-negative integer (0 allowed); `\g<0>` will refer to the whole text matched by the expression.

---

If you want to double up all characters except new line:

```
re.sub(r"(.)", r"\1\1", text.read())
```

---

If you want to double up all characters (new line included):

```
re.sub(r"(.)", r"\1\1", text.read(), 0, re.S)
```

Answer (score 9):

You can use the `pandas` library and the `replace` function. I represent one example with five replacements:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'text': ['Billy is going to visit Rome in November', 'I was born in 10/10/2010', 'I will be there at 20:00']})

to_replace=['Billy','Rome','January|February|March|April|May|June|July|August|September|October|November|December', '\d{2}:\d{2}', '\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}']
replace_with=['name','city','month','time', 'date']

print(df.text.replace(to_replace, replace_with, regex=True))
```

And the modified text is:

```
0    name is going to visit city in month
1                      I was born in date
2                 I will be there at time
```

You can find the example [here](https://predictivehacks.com/replace-a-list-of-characters-with-a-list-of-characters-of-text-in-python/)

Comment: In my case this was less efficient than using regular expressions directly, maybe there are some contexts where this is not the case?

Comment: In case you want to apply multiple replacements at once in a pandas data frame using vectorization

Answer (score 9):

None of the other solutions work if your patterns are themselves regexes.

For that, you need:

```py
def multi_sub(pairs, s):
    def repl_func(m):
        # only one group will be present, use the corresponding match
        return next(
            repl
            for (patt, repl), group in zip(pairs, m.groups())
            if group is not None
        )
    pattern = '|'.join("({})".format(patt) for patt, _ in pairs)
    return re.sub(pattern, repl_func, s)
```

Which can be used as:

```
>>> multi_sub([
...     ('a+b', 'Ab'),
...     ('b', 'B'),
...     ('a+', 'A.'),
... ], "aabbaa")  # matches as (aab)(b)(aa)
'AbBA.'
```

Note that this solution does not allow you to put capturing groups in your regexes, or use them in replacements.

Comment: This is a much better solution than the accepted answer. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Has there been some change in Python that breaks this? I used this snippet successfully in Python 3.10 about half a year ago. Now I noticed, in the meanwhile having switched to Python 3.11, that `multi_sub` as above doesn't replace anything anymore. My code hasn't changed, nor has the input, but the output is completely unmodified now. (If I split it back up into multiple `re.sub` calls, everything works again, of course).

Answer (score 6):

Using tips from [how to make a 'stringy' class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/820742/how-to-bestow-string-ness-on-my-class), we can make an object identical to a string but for an extra `sub` method:

```
import re
class Substitutable(str):
  def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
    newobj = str.__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
    newobj.sub = lambda fro,to: Substitutable(re.sub(fro, to, newobj))
    return newobj
```

This allows to use the builder pattern, which looks nicer, but works only for a pre-determined number of substitutions. If you use it in a loop, there is no point creating an extra class anymore. E.g.

```
>>> h = Substitutable('horse')
>>> h
'horse'
>>> h.sub('h', 'f')
'forse'
>>> h.sub('h', 'f').sub('f','h')
'horse'
```

Answer (score 3):

I found I had to modify Emmett J. Butler's code by changing the lambda function to use myDict.get(mo.group(1),mo.group(1)).  The original code wasn't working for me; using myDict.get() also provides the benefit of a default value if a key is not found.

```
OIDNameContraction = {
                                'Fucntion':'Func',
                                'operated':'Operated',
                                'Asist':'Assist',
                                'Detection':'Det',
                                'Control':'Ctrl',
                                'Function':'Func'
}

replacementDictRegex = re.compile("(%s)" % "|".join(map(re.escape, OIDNameContraction.keys())))

oidDescriptionStr = replacementDictRegex.sub(lambda mo:OIDNameContraction.get(mo.group(1),mo.group(1)), oidDescriptionStr)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you dealing with files, I have a simple python code about this problem.
More info [here](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/81330-single-pass-multiple-replace/).

```
import re 

 def multiple_replace(dictionary, text):
  # Create a regular expression  from the dictionaryary keys

  regex = re.compile("(%s)" % "|".join(map(re.escape, dictionary.keys())))

  # For each match, look-up corresponding value in dictionaryary
  String = lambda mo: dictionary[mo.string[mo.start():mo.end()]]
  return regex.sub(String , text)


if __name__ == "__main__":

dictionary = {
    "Wiley Online Library" : "Wiley",
    "Chemical Society Reviews" : "Chem. Soc. Rev.",
} 

with open ('LightBib.bib', 'r') as Bib_read:
    with open ('Abbreviated.bib', 'w') as Bib_write:
        read_lines = Bib_read.readlines()
        for rows in read_lines:
            #print(rows)
            text = rows
            new_text = multiple_replace(dictionary, text)
            #print(new_text)
            Bib_write.write(new_text)
```

Answer (score 1):

I dont know why most of the solutions try to compose a single regex pattern instead of replacing multiple times. This answer is just for the sake of completeness.

That being said, the output of this approach is different than the output of the combined regex approach. Namely, repeated substitutions may evolve the text over time. However, the following function returns the same output as a call to unix sed would:

```py
def multi_replace(rules, data: str) -> str:
    ret = data
    for pattern, repl in rules:
        ret = re.sub(pattern, repl, ret)
    return ret
```

usage:

```py
RULES = [
    (r'a', r'b'),
    (r'b', r'c'),
    (r'c', r'd'),
]
multi_replace(RULES, 'ab')  # output: dd
```

With the same input and rules, the other solutions will output "bc". Depending on your use case you may or may not want to replace strings consecutively. In my case I wanted to rebuild the sed behavior. Also, note that the order of rules matters. If you reverse the rule order, this example would also return "bc".

This solution is faster than combining the patterns into a single regex (by a factor of 100). So, if your use-case allows it, you should prefer the repeated substitution method.

---

Of course, you can compile the regex patterns:

```py
class Sed:
    def __init__(self, rules) -> None:
        self._rules = [(re.compile(pattern), sub) for pattern, sub in rules]

    def replace(self, data: str) -> str:
        ret = data
        for regx, repl in self._rules:
            ret = regx.sub(repl, ret)
        return ret
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on [Eric's great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61952495/8083662), I came up with a more general solution that is capable of handling capturing groups and backreferences:

```
import re
from itertools import islice

def multiple_replace(s, repl_dict):
    groups_no = [re.compile(pattern).groups for pattern in repl_dict]

    def repl_func(m):
        all_groups = m.groups()

        # Use 'i' as the index within 'all_groups' and 'j' as the main
        # group index.
        i, j = 0, 0

        while i < len(all_groups) and all_groups[i] is None:
            # Skip the inner groups and move on to the next group.
            i += (groups_no[j] + 1)

            # Advance the main group index.
            j += 1

        # Extract the pattern and replacement at the j-th position.
        pattern, repl = next(islice(repl_dict.items(), j, j + 1))

        return re.sub(pattern, repl, all_groups[i])

    # Create the full pattern using the keys of 'repl_dict'.
    full_pattern = '|'.join(f'({pattern})' for pattern in repl_dict)

    return re.sub(full_pattern, repl_func, s)
```

**Example.** Calling the above with

```
s = 'This is a sample string. Which is getting replaced. 1234-5678.'

REPL_DICT = {
    r'(.*?)is(.*?)ing(.*?)ch': r'\3-\2-\1',
    r'replaced': 'REPLACED',
    r'\d\d((\d)(\d)-(\d)(\d))\d\d': r'__\5\4__\3\2__',
    r'get|ing': '!@#'
}
```

gives:

```
>>> multiple_replace(s, REPL_DICT)
'. Whi- is a sample str-Th is !@#t!@# REPLACED. __65__43__.'
```

For a more efficient solution, one can create a simple wrapper to precompute `groups_no` and `full_pattern`, e.g.

```
import re
from itertools import islice

class ReplWrapper:
    def __init__(self, repl_dict):
        self.repl_dict = repl_dict
        self.groups_no = [re.compile(pattern).groups for pattern in repl_dict]
        self.full_pattern = '|'.join(f'({pattern})' for pattern in repl_dict)

    def get_pattern_repl(self, pos):
        return next(islice(self.repl_dict.items(), pos, pos + 1))

    def multiple_replace(self, s):
        def repl_func(m):
            all_groups = m.groups()

            # Use 'i' as the index within 'all_groups' and 'j' as the main
            # group index.
            i, j = 0, 0

            while i < len(all_groups) and all_groups[i] is None:
                # Skip the inner groups and move on to the next group.
                i += (self.groups_no[j] + 1)

                # Advance the main group index.
                j += 1

            return re.sub(*self.get_pattern_repl(j), all_groups[i])

        return re.sub(self.full_pattern, repl_func, s)
```

Use it as follows:

```
>>> ReplWrapper(REPL_DICT).multiple_replace(s)
'. Whi- is a sample str-Th is !@#t!@# REPLACED. __65__43__.'
```

Answer (score 0):

In my context, I can use only expressions and re.sub, so here is a single line solution (derived from other solutions in fact) :

`import re`

`xx = "a&amp;b&lt;c"`

`yy = re.sub('&((amp)|(lt));', lambda x: ' and ' if x.group(2) else (' less ' if x.group(3) else ''), xx)`