# Multiple, specific, regex substitutions in Python

Tags: python, regex, substitution

What I would like to do is to make specific substitions in a given text. For example, '<' should be changed to '[', '>' to ']', and so forth. It is similar to the solution given here:
[How can I do multiple substitutions using regex in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15175142/how-can-i-do-multiple-substitutions-using-regex-in-python), which is

```
import re 

def multiple_replace(dict, text):
  # Create a regular expression  from the dictionary keys
  regex = re.compile("(%s)" % "|".join(map(re.escape, dict.keys())))

  # For each match, look-up corresponding value in dictionary
  return regex.sub(lambda mo: dict[mo.string[mo.start():mo.end()]], text)
```

Now, the problem is that I would also like to replace regex-matched patterns. For example, I want to replace 'fo.+' with 'foo' and 'ba[rz]*' with 'bar'.

Removing the map(re.escape in the code helps, so that the regex actually matches, but I then receive key errors, because, for example, 'barzzzzzz' would be a match, and something I want to replace, but 'barzzzzzz' isn't a key in the dictionary, the literal string 'ba[rz]*' is. How can I modify this function to work?

(On an unrelated note, where do these 'foo' and 'bar' things come from?)

Comment: Replacing literals is easy to keep straight, but adding regex as match patterns definitely adds some potential ambiguity (esp. since you may have a couple of dozen of them to keep track of). Take care if you have regex that may overlap, that you test and replace them in the intended order.

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66270091/multiple-regex-substitutions-using-a-dict-with-regex-expressions-as-keys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import re

def multiple_replace(dict, text):
  # Create a regular expression  from the dictionary keys
  regex = re.compile(r'(%s)' % "|".join(dict.keys()))
  return regex.sub(lambda mo: dict[
      [ k for k in dict if
      re.search(k, mo.string[mo.start():mo.end()])
      ][0]], text)

d = { r'ba[rz]*' : 'bar', '<' : '[' }
s = 'barzzzzzz <'

print multiple_replace(d, s)
```

*Gives:*

```
bar [
```

Answer (score 2):

Just do multiple `sub` calls.

On an unrelated note, Jargon File to the rescue: [Metasyntactic variables](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/M/metasyntactic-variable.html), [foo](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/F/foo.html).

Comment: Multiple sub calls is an option, but not when I've got a few dozen different replacements to make throughout a text. Thanks for the link, though!

Comment: Just to put things in perspective - you don't like doing a few dozen `sub` calls, but you're okay with doing a few thousand or million `search` calls? @perreal's solution answers your literal question very well, but I still think if you benchmark it, you might find that just doing multiple `sub` calls is both simpler and faster.

Comment: ... Huh. I'll try benchmarking it, but I did initially think that this way would be faster.

Comment: Well, I've benchmarked it. As it turns out, the multiple_replace function is significantly slower than multiple `re.sub`s, and it seems to scale exponentially with the number of substitutions.