# Recursive regex in Python to match balanced brackets and replace

Tags: python, regex, recursion, regex-group

I have some LaTeX source and have some annotations: three types:

- `\ins{who}{what}`
- `\rem{who}{what}`
- `\rpl{who}{whatold}{whatnew}`

The goal is to run through the source files and replace all occurences in the following manner:

```
\ins{who}{what}->what
\rem{who}{what}->''
\rpl{who}{whatold}{whatnew}->whatnew
```

My initial idea was `python` + `regex` but as you can see on the example below, one quickly runs to the balanced braces issue. Based on the discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/546433/regular-expression-to-match-balanced-parentheses), i came up with the regex for replace as `\\rpl\{[a-z]{2}\}(\{((?>[^}{]+|(?1))*)\})(\{((?>[^}{]+|(?3))*)\})` with replacement with fourth group. I verified on regex101 for PCRE2. But I am having hard time getting this to work in Python.

The simplistic test is:

```
import regex

text = 'Velit sed ullamcorper morbi tincidunt ornare. Lorem dolor sed viverra ipsum nunc aliquet bibendum enim.\rpl{dd}{ Pellentesque \qtyrange{10}{20}{\celsius} habitant morbi \qtyrange{10}{20}{\celsius} tristique senectus \gls{abc}.}{Some new text with \qtyrange{10}{20}{\celsius} and more \gls{cdf}.}'
regx = r'\\rpl\{[a-z]{2}\}(\{((?>[^}{]+|(?1))*)\})(\{((?>[^}{]+|(?3))*)\})'

print(regex.findall(regx, text, overlapped=False))
```

The expected output from the test should be:

```
'Velit sed ullamcorper morbi tincidunt ornare. Lorem dolor sed viverra ipsum nunc aliquet bibendum enim.Some new text with \qtyrange{10}{20}{\celsius} and more \gls{cdf}.'
```

In the discussions mentioned, some people advised against using regex and implementing bracket counting. But I am trying to avoid that, i feel it is too much programing when the tool is there and seems to work in other flavours.

Any advise how to modify the regex or whether to use other language feature than regex that is able to do this? The advantage of regex is that I can easily match what should be around.

Comment: Your regex only matches `\rpl` segments, what about `\ins` and `\rem` ?

Comment: @anubhava I added under the sample problem. In the case of whatever starts with `\rpl`, the output should be whatever is enclosed in the third curly brackets.pl{text1}{text_with_more balanced curly brackets}{replacement}` .

Comment: @anubhava I have not gotten so far yet. My guess was if I manage to do `\rpl` the rest would follow easily. My plan is to use dictionary with lambda function as is done here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66270091/multiple-regex-substitutions-using-a-dict-with-regex-expressions-as-keys

Comment: Then if you plan to replace, why use `findall`? `regex.sub(that_pattern, r'\4', text)`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I am really just testing the regex as of now, which is where I am stuck (baby steps)

Comment: You need to declare your text as `text = r'...'` (raw string)

Comment: See [this demo](https://tio.run/##fVHNTsMwDL73KXxrC6NiG1fYC3BAQuKyDCltzBYpTTrH2TpCnr20HScOO1iyPtnfj91d@ODsehh02zliINxjn2WMPcMzUP6BRjN4VBCMkW3jqEOC1lGtgbVttAqWwZGVhBW8OsIWlDOO5p2TPiGRBN350IINtgFp9DEgQ61rtGpE0eq2EtSZqFSK8IbGoGX04xSII19I2j3G5WOKq7FEg8br4BMcZK1ZjuJXM7dGmbTnSXY0ZbHh4EHsjY@yblKV4rtrESyeYU591ny4ySatmjTxytGor5Ejz8bD9fPFxJRFxK18@N7FVRKpELEoNi/bzxR39z/FZlmWd6VI5X98/YfnWdaRtlzMv6h8qKeuX0zcT/lidlmW2TD8Ag), is it working as expected?

Answer (score 1):

This regex should work for you for all the 3 cases using PyPi `regex` module's recursive bracket matching:

```bash
\\(ins|rpl|rem){[a-z]{2}}({((?>[^}{]+|(?2))*)}){1,2}
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/lnUBa0/1)

**Code:**

```bash
import regex

text = r'Velit sed ullamcorper morbi tincidunt ornare. Lorem dolor sed viverra ipsum nunc aliquet bibendum enim.\rpl{dd}{ Pellentesque \qtyrange{10}{20}{\celsius} habitant morbi \qtyrange{10}{20}{\celsius} tristique senectus \gls{abc}.}{Some new text with \qtyrange{10}{20}{\celsius} and more \gls{cdf}.} and here is \ins{aa}{ins text with \qtyrange{20}{40}{\celsius} and more \gls{xyz}.} but we must ignore \rem{bb}{what} last part'

rx = regex.compile(r'\\(ins|rpl|rem){[a-z]{2}}({((?>[^}{]+|(?2))*)}){1,2}')

print (rx.sub(lambda m: m.group(3) if m.group(1) != 'rem' else '', text))
```

**Output:**

> `Velit sed ullamcorper morbi tincidunt ornare. Lorem dolor sed viverra ipsum nunc aliquet bibendum enim.Some new text with \qtyrange{10}{20}{\celsius} and more \gls{cdf}. and here is ins text with \qtyrange{20}{40}{\celsius} and more \gls{xyz}. but we must ignore  last part`

Note how we are altering substitution part in the lambda function based on the first group which would be `ins` or `rpl` or `rem`. Also note that input text must also be a raw string to preserve backslashes.

[Code Demo](https://tio.run/##fZHJbtwwDIbvfgr2ZKtNjM6kpwJpXiCHAgV6iVNAshmbgBaHljKeaPTsU3oC9FTMQSDE5fu5zMc4BX93PpObA0dgHHGtqohrhHvg@jdairDgAMla7frAMzK4wIYgku9pSD5CYK8ZW3gMjA6GYANfat7oDZk10LwkBz75HrSl14QRDBn0g3jRk2s7nm0ehpLhJ1qLPuIiWdC9xiNrP2LefS15L6/r0S6UlgKTNhS1iH80cy01Mi1xk5WmPPYxLdCNdsna9KUt@VdwCB4PcJn6QHG6StN@2DTxg9EPL8K4OCcUJwmbvLB1yWL/y9x4364w1@P7xjRJKhFcWiLQ6C9h2W82puTDpGMBqyU0a451VfG6HWw7X9sHN5PFhuuua6SJk2z3JJUqP@nb9@e8L6XJTfPw4@lPyc9fTs3DXqnPqqi8u9mXWlXVzCSbbXhtl2QaObwZNLjv4NqRQ5qbOwX08u@3U/DpHmpRqEEmQqjrm8vgSlXn818)