# Multiple regex substitutions

Tags: python, regex

I am using the following code to normalize a file's name:

```
new_file = re.sub('[. ]', '_', old_file.lower())
new_file = re.sub('__+', '_', new_file)
new_file = re.sub('[][)(}{]',  '', new_file)
new_file = re.sub('[-_]([^-_]+)$',  r'.\1', new_file)
```

My question is there a possibility to write this code in a better way?

I found the [following example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15175142/how-can-i-do-multiple-substitutions-using-regex-in-python):

```
def multiple_replace(dict, text):
    # Create a regular expression  from the dictionary keys
    regex = re.compile("(%s)" % "|".join(map(re.escape, dict.keys())))

    # For each match, look-up corresponding value in dictionary
    return regex.sub(lambda mo: dict[mo.string[mo.start():mo.end()]], text) 

dict = {
    "Larry Wall" : "Guido van Rossum",
    "creator" : "Benevolent Dictator for Life",
    "Perl" : "Python",
}
```

But this code only works with normal strings. The `map(re.escape, ...` in line 3 "destroys" the Regex.

Regards,
Ray

Comment: Have you tried simply removing the `re.escape`, i.e. changing the offending line to `regex = re.compile("(%s)" % "|".join(dict))`? I haven't tried it, but I see no reason why it shouldn't work.

Comment: I tried this already. In this case there is an error in line 5. Futhermore in my example the sequence is important and I figured out that the a dictionary messes up the sequence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're simply looking for more maintainable and less repetitive code (as opposed to algorithmic change), go with a simple `for` loop:

```
SUBS = [
  ('[. ]', '_'),
  ('__+', '_'),
  ('[][)(}{]',  ''),
  ('[-_]([^-_]+)$',  r'.\1'),
]

def normalize(name):
    name = name.lower()
    for pattern, replacement in SUBS:
        name = re.sub(pattern, replacement, name)
    return name
```

Comment: I would encourage OP to merge `('[. ]', '_')` and `('__+', '_')` into `('[. _]+', '_')` which is effectively the same without becoming a horribly unreadable regex.

Comment: @user4815162342: Thanks for your solution. I like it and I will use it in my code...