# is there a way to replace and remove lines of a multi-lines string

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to process a multi-lines string, replace and remove some lines. here is the code.

```
>>> txt
'1 Introduction\nPart I: Applied Math and Machine Learning Basics\n2 Linear Algebra'
>>> tmp = []
>>> for line in txt.splitlines():
...     if re.findall('[0-9]', line):
...         replaced = re.sub('[0-9]', '#', line)
...         tmp.append(replaced)
>>> print(tmp)
['# Introduction', '# Linear Algebra']
```

this piece of code has done my job though, I am not sure if it is the most efficient way.

i tried this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15175142/how-can-i-do-multiple-substitutions-using-regex-in-python) and [doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.MatchObject.group), it seems that none of their multiple find is for multi-lines.

is there a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your code. You can compress it into a single line using a list comprehension: `[re.sub('[0-9]', '#', line) for line in txt.splitlines() if re.findall('[0-9]', line)]` if it looks more readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use list comprehension for the code you provided in the question, this makes the code neat.

```
[re.sub('[0-9]', '#', line) for line in txt.splitlines() if re.findall('[0-9]', line) ]

# Output 
['# Introduction', '# Linear Algebra']
```

Also, like @CertainPerformance have mentioned in the comments, as you just want to know whether a number is present in the string it is better to use `search` instead of `findall`. Then you can re-write the list comprehension code as,

```
[re.sub('[0-9]', '#', line) for line in txt.splitlines() if re.search('[0-9]', line) ]

# Output 
['# Introduction', '# Linear Algebra']
```

I can see a small performance improvement while using `search` in my machine.

```
%%timeit 1000000

[re.sub('[0-9]', '#', line) for line in txt.splitlines() if re.search('[0-9]', line) ]

# 4.76 µs ± 53.7 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

%%timeit 1000000

[re.sub('[0-9]', '#', line) for line in txt.splitlines() if re.findall('[0-9]', line) ]

# 5.21 µs ± 114 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```