# anti-vowel using Nested loop having index error in python2

Tags: python, indexing, error-handling

I'm doing the anti_vowel function, which basically takes out all of the vowels from the input,and I have some bugs there.
Here is my code down below

```
def anti_vowel(text):
  vowel="aeiouAEIOU"
  for i in range(len(text)-1):
    for h in range(len(vowel)-1):
      if text[i]==vowel[h]:
        text=text.replace(text[i],"")

  return text      



print anti_vowel("HELLO")
```

If I input "HELLO",it will success to print"HLL".But if I changed my input to"Hey look Words!",
it shows error
**IndexError: string index out of range**.I am very grateful if someone can help me solving this problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I do multiple substitutions using regex in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15175142/how-can-i-do-multiple-substitutions-using-regex-in-python)

Comment: You change the collection you are iterating over. It will fail if the second vowel is before the last character. Try the input "EEL" This may be better: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3939381/1766544

Comment: The whole function body could be reduced to  `return ''.join(character for character in text if character not in 'aeiouAEIOU')`. If you want to learn Python then try to understand this code.

Comment: @Matthias Thanks  a lot,it is such a simple code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue you are having is, that `.replace()` replaces all instances that occur in your text. Therefore when calling `.replace("o","")` you are replacing all "o"s in your sentence, which then makes your sentence shorter. So an `IndexError` occurs.

Take a look at this:

```py
def anti_vowel(text):
  vowel="aeiouAEIOU"
  for i in range(len(text)-1):
    for h in range(len(vowel)-1):
      print(i,h, text)
      if text[i]==vowel[h]:
        text=text.replace(text[i],"")

  return text      

print(anti_vowel("Heel!"))
```

Output:

```
0 0 Heel!
0 1 Heel!
0 2 Heel!
0 3 Heel!
0 4 Heel!
0 5 Heel!
0 6 Heel!
0 7 Heel!
0 8 Heel!
1 0 Heel!
1 1 Heel!
1 2 Hl!
1 3 Hl!
1 4 Hl!
1 5 Hl!
1 6 Hl!
1 7 Hl!
1 8 Hl!
2 0 Hl!
2 1 Hl!
2 2 Hl!
2 3 Hl!
2 4 Hl!
2 5 Hl!
2 6 Hl!
2 7 Hl!
2 8 Hl!
3 0 Hl!
```

That's when the `IndexError` occurs. As you can see when trying to replace the first 'e' all 'e's are replaced.

I flagged your question with another SO-post where it is shown how you can do such an operation successfully.

Comment: This may be easier to demonstrate with the input "EEL"

Comment: @Nils Thanks for  your help, I modified my program and successfully execute my code.