# How to use regex to replace tokens in text in Python

Tags: python, python-re

Given a list of tokens, I want to replace all the tokens in tokenized text with whitespace.

For example, given `['a', 'is']` and `'this is a test'`, the result should be `'this test'`.

I tried the code from [How can I do multiple substitutions using regex in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15175142/how-can-i-do-multiple-substitutions-using-regex-in-python), but the output is `'th test'`.

Besides, the list is long (about 1k tokens) and the text file is large. so the speed is also important.

Comment: You are not actually replacing with space, in your sample output you have deleted the token not replaced them with `space`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should solve your answer and be reasonable fast. The token list is converted to a set so lookup can be done in O(1) time:

```py
tokens = ['a', 'is']
tokenized_text = 'this is a test'

val = ' '.join(word for word in tokenized_text.split(' ')
               if word not in set(tokens))
print(val)
```

Prints

```py
this test
```