# Replace a list of elements with regex

Tags: python, regex

I have a text full of adverbes and it's replacements like this :

```
adverbe1 |replacement1
adverbe2 |replacement2
adverbe3 |replacement3
```

And i want the adverbes to replaced in my text:

**Example :**

```
'Hello adverbe1 this is a test' to be this : 'Hello replacement1 this is a test'
```

but am runing out of solutions, my code so far:

```
adverbes = open("list_adverbes_replacement.txt", encoding="utf-8")
list_adverbes = []
list_replacement = []
for ad in adverbes.readlines():
    if ad != '' and ad.split('|')[0].strip(' ')[-3:] == 'ent':
        list_adverbes.append(ad.split('|')[0].strip(' '))
        list_replacement.append(ad.split('|')[1])
pattern = r"(\s+\b(?:{}))\b".format("|".join(list_adverbes))
data = re.sub(pattern, r"\1", data)
```

I couldn't find a way to replace each adverbes with the appropriate replacement.

the `list_adverbes_replacement.txt` is the text i gave in the beginning, and please am looking for a regex solution, i just don't know what am missing.

Comment: This is not a regular expression problem.  Just split the sentence into words using `split()`, then check each word against your list, and put them back together with `join()`.

Comment: @TimRoberts: why split? Isn't replace enough?

Comment: Looks like this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15175142/how-can-i-do-multiple-substitutions-using-regex

Comment: @ThomasWeller  The problem with `replace` is that it doesn't honor word boundaries.  It would replace "have" in "I shaved today".

Comment: @svrist excuse me but i didn't understand the code right there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple and concise approach. Build a dictionary of key/value pairs for your replacements.

Then replace them using regex' `re.sub` by matching on each word, looking up the word in the dictionary, and defaulting to the word itself if it's not in the dictionary

```py
import re

d = dict()
with open('list_adverbes_replacement.txt', 'r') as fo:
    for line in fo:
        splt = line.split('|')
        d[splt[0].strip()] = splt[1].strip()

s = 'Hello adverbe1 this is a test, adverbe2'
s = re.sub(r'(\w+)', lambda m: d.get(m.group(), m.group()), s)
print(s)
```

Comment: @user16085212 Note this code will have to check each word in the input, and if the input is a long text, it might take some time to go through it.

Answer (score 0):

Given Adverbs like this:

```py
adverbs =  '''adverbe1 |replacement1
adverbe2 |replacement2
adverbe3 |replacement3'''
```

Create a dictionary out of it where key is the adverb and value is the replacement text.

```py
adverbsDict = {item[0].strip():item[1].strip() for item in map(lambda x: x.split('|'), adverbs.split('\n'))}
```

Now iterate through each keys, and just call replace on the text for the given key with the corresponding value:

```py
text = 'Hello adverbe1 this is a test'
for key in adverbsDict:
    text = text.replace(key, adverbsDict[key])
```

**OUTPUT**:

```py
'Hello replacement1 this is a test'
```

Comment: I updated the answer @user16085212 , `replace` was missing `key` parameter

Comment: This solution will end up replacing `me` in `home`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, yes that is undeniably True

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize the dictionary with adverbs and replacements using

```py
dct = {}
with open(r'__t.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        items = line.strip().split('|')
        dct[items[0].strip()] = items[1].strip()
```

The `dct` will look like `{'adverbe1': 'replacement1', 'adverbe2': 'replacement2', 'adverbe3': 'replacement3'}`.

Then, `pip install triegex` (or use this solution from [Speed up millions of regex replacements in Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42789508/3832970)) to streamline dynamic regex building and use

```py
import triegex, re

dct = {}
with open(PATH_TO_FILE_WITH_SEARCH_AND_REPLACEMENTS, 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        items = line.strip().split('|')
        dct[items[0].strip()] = items[1].strip()

test = 'Hello adverbe1 this is a test'
pattern = re.compile(fr'\b{triegex.Triegex(*dct.keys()).to_regex()}')
print( pattern.sub(lambda x: dct[x.group()], test) )
# => Hello replacement1 this is a test
```

The pattern for this demo dictionary is `\b(?:adverbe(?:1\b|2\b|3\b)|~^(?#match nothing))`, and it matches `adverbe1`, `adverbe2`, `adverbe3` as whole words.

The `lambda x: dct[x.group()]`, the replacement argument to `re.sub`, gets the corresponding replacement value.

Comment: it gives me an error in the line : for line in f

Comment: i did solve it, but i don't know why the code isn't working!! it doesn't replace anything and yet the dict if full and contanis everything

Comment: @user16085212 Use the real file path instead of `r'__t.txt'`, and it does replace, since I just copied the output from my Python console.

Comment: yes wiktor i did replace it with the correct name but didn't work.

Comment: @user16085212 This just means you did not actually use my code since it is working fine. Just re-tried.

Comment: i did use your code @Wiktor it just didn't work, it's working fine but doesn't replace the adverbe as it should be