# How to speed up pandas apply function with for loops? (Python)

Tags: python, replace, apply

I am working on texts for my project.
I want to replace words in my dataset texts by looking all words in dictionary.
My dictionary is like this;
`replacement_dict ={'t1' : 'tebir', 't2':'teki', 'number':'no', ...}`

Example text in dataframe;
`"Hello my t1 is not okey, please help my number is bla bla"` Will be ;
`"Hello my tebir is not okey, please help my no is bla bla"`

I wrote following code;

```
import pandas
def replacament(row,replacement_dict):  
    text = row['text']
    text = text.lower()
    for i, j in replacement_dict.items():
        text = re.sub(r"\b%s\b" % i, j, text)          
    return text
data['text2'] = data.apply(replacament, axis = 1, args=(replacement_dict,))
```

But it takes 8 hour to complete. My date set row size is 600000. How can i speed up this apply function?
Thanks,

Comment: You could use the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/15175239/1862861 to at least remove the for loop from your `replacement` function, which will hopefully provide some speed up.

Comment: Pandas has its own regular expression replace, including a case-insensitive flag... https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html *(Avoiding apply, lower, etc, altogether.)*

Comment: you can use something like this: first `data['text2'] = data['text'].str.lower()` then `for k, v in replacement_dict.items():
    data['text2'] = data['text'].str.replace(r'\b%s\b' % k, v)`

Answer (score 1):

`apply` can be rather slow but pandas has a `replace` function which can be used by first forming another dictionary with regex expression to replace only whole words (assuming you want to only replace words not substrings within words) as below. Takes about 10-15 secs for 600,000 rows.

```
d = {r'(\b){}(\b)'.format(k):r'\1{}\2'.format(v) for k,v in replacement_dict.items()}
df['text2'] = df['text'].str.lower().replace(d, regex = True)
```

Comment: You missed the `lower()` part of the OP. Needs to be case-insensitive.

Comment: @MatBailie Thanks. Answer edited. I was thinking on the basis that there were no caps in the OP text.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`pandas.DataFrame.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) function.

Use it like this, with regex argument at True

```py
import pandas

test = pandas.DataFrame({"name": ["Good morning England", "Land and Freedom", "This is England"]})
replace_dict = {"England" : "French", "morning": "night"}

test["name"] = test["name"].replace(replace_dict, regex=True)
print(test)
```

The test dataframe is now :

```
                name
0  Good night French
1   Land and Freedom
2     This is French
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, where can i add lower function in this replace function

Comment: @Melcore, If there is a value called `wwEnglandww` in the dataframe, the output will be `wwFrenchww`. So your solution is not quite correct. You have to use the regex rule (\b%s\b)

Comment: dictionary elements are already applied lower, so i  only need to lower dataframe texts

Comment: but this texts are turkish, so i was using unicode_tr(text).lower()

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `swifter` (https://github.com/jmcarpenter2/swifter) + `pandas.DataFrame.replace` helps to u (`pip install swifter`).

I updated your input and created 600K row for the test. It takes 1.43 secs.

**Code:**

```
import re
import swifter
import pandas as pd
import time

data = pd.DataFrame({'text': ["t2 my t1 is not okey, number please help my  is bla bla"] * 600000})
replacement_dict = {'t1': 'tebir', 't2': 'teki', 'number': 'no'}

start_time = time.time()
def replace_text(text):
    for k, v in replacement_dict.items():
        text = text.replace(k, v)
    return text

data['text2_parallel'] = data['text'].swifter.apply(replace_text)
parallel_time = time.time() - start_time
print(f"Parallelized time: {parallel_time:.2f} seconds")
print(data[['text2_parallel']])
```

**Output:**

```
Pandas Apply: 100%|████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 600000/600000 [00:01<00:00, 458107.50it/s]
Parallelized time: 1.43 seconds
                                           text2_parallel
0       teki my tebir is not okey, no please help my  ...
1       teki my tebir is not okey, no please help my  ...
2       teki my tebir is not okey, no please help my  ...
3       teki my tebir is not okey, no please help my  ...
4       teki my tebir is not okey, no please help my  ...
...                                                   ...
599995  teki my tebir is not okey, no please help my  ...
599996  teki my tebir is not okey, no please help my  ...
599997  teki my tebir is not okey, no please help my  ...
599998  teki my tebir is not okey, no please help my  ...
599999  teki my tebir is not okey, no please help my  ...

[600000 rows x 1 columns]
```